# Pandas - join two dataframes on substring/intersection

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have two dataframes with many columns, and each of dataframes has column ID which can be used in joining (SQL inner join type with more then one match acceptable). In output I need to have dataframe with all columns from both dataframes so I wanted to use pd.merge. The tricky part is that join cannot be done by simple comparing ID_1 = ID_2 and rather done on common substring. Here is how sample of data can look like (all data type is string) and what is expected:

[image]

I have tried to find intersection between ID_1 and ID_2 and then use it in left_on/right_on condition in pd.merge. Here is what I've tried:

Create sample of two dataframes:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID_1': ['[COL_63334]', '[COL_63339, DNB_64268]', '[COL_67319, COL_94485]', '[COL_76540]', '[DNB_35923, DNB_23999, COL_30000]']})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID_2': ['[COL_63334, COL_63335, COL_63337, DNB_64268]', '[COL_63335, COL_63338, DNB_64268]', '[COL_94485]', '[COL_98341, COL_23144]', '[COL_5600, DNB_35923, DNB_36999, COL_30000]']})
```

Convert data to list:

```
df_1['ID_1'] = df_1.ID_1.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(', '))
df_2['ID_2'] = df_2.ID_2.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(', '))
```

Find intersection of two list by means of:

```
df_1['intersect'] = set(df_1.ID_1).intersection(df_2.ID_2)
```

Find intersection of two list by means of:

```
[x for x in df_1.ID_1 if x in df_2.ID_2]
```

Both methods for finding intersection returned this error:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Looks like you are trying to compare rows with the same index only. Is this intentional?

Comment: BTw is that list ? or it just a string ?

Comment: @coldspeed My intention is to join two dataframes based on substring between ID_1 and ID_2. The same way as SQL inner join works. Search for matching should be not limited to matching index.

Comment: What do you mean by "substring"? It seems like you would want to join rows if the intersection of their IDs is not a null set. Is this right? Can you fix your explanation please?

Comment: @W-B Raw type of data in ID_1 and ID_2 is string (as well as for all data in df_1 and df_2). My idea was to convert it to list and use list intersection to find common key for joining.

Comment: Based on this intersection logic, you should have 5 rows in the output, not 3.

Comment: Agree with coldspeed, you should have 5 rows